# setting Form.Text in WinForms Form does not update the title

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this piece of code in my routine but it doesnt seem to work:

```
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Text = "Elvis " + AssemblyVersion;
}
```

In my designer I had set the form title to "Elvis". I see that the AssemblyVersion info gets added to the text properly but the title doesnt get updated at all. I've tried refresh, invalidate etc, but nothing works. Any idea how I can update the title at runtime?

I am using .NET 3.5 and VS 2008.

thanks

Comment: Make sure you are running the freshly builded executable...

Comment: Could you post a short but complete program that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This generally works just fine. Setting the `Text` property of a Form will change the title of the window. So can you post more code? It's possible your Text property is later getting overwritten without you realizing it.

Comment: Yes, indeed!! I was using a third party library that was reverting for some strange reason to the original title whenever I changed the title. Thanks!!

Comment: I have a similar problem, I hooked into the TextChanged event to see if any other component is using the Forms Text Property - its not. It works in one Setup Method (User) but not in the other Setup(admin). Refreshing/Update/Invalidate wont do the trick, only resizing the form brings up the desired Text. Only soultion I have found so far is resizing by code:  Me.Size = New Size(Me.Size.Width + 1, Me.Size.Height)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was because of the Initialize components function that is changing the form's header, if you set the header using the constructor, it will be overwritten with the InitializeComponents function value.
Solution: remove the form's property set in the InitializeComponent function.

Best regards,
Chen

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this

```
this.Text = "Elvis " + AssemblyVersion;
```

on the onload event